# Insert JSON to Posgres table

Tags: java, sql, json, hibernate, postgresql

In my Java app I would like to insert a new record to a Postgres table which one of its column is JSON type.

I use Hibernate 4.x

The entity class looks like this:

```
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(
                    name = "user.login", 
                    query = "select * from user_login(:ext_user_id, :platform_id,     :server_id, :ip_address, :first_name, :last_name, :additional_data)",
                    resultClass = User.class                        
                )
})
public class User implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

The actual code:

```
Session session = sessionManager.openDBSession();

Query query = session.getNamedQuery("user.login");

PGobject data = new PGobject();
data.setType("json");
data.setValue(additional_data.toString());

query.setString("ext_user_id", ext_uid)
    .setShort("platform_id", (short)platform_id.value())
    .setShort("server_id", server_id)
    .setString("ip_address", ip_address)
    .setString("first_name", fname)
    .setString("last_name", lname)
    .setParameter("additional_data", data);

    UUID sessionId = (UUID) query.uniqueResult();

...
```

}

This fails with an error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function user_login(character varying, smallint, smallint,    
character varying, character varying, character varying, bytea) does not exist
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Position: 55
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: it looks like the table column additional_data is bytea, not json. i don't know much about java, but, you will need an BYTEAobject data to do what you want to do in place of PGobject.

Comment: Do you think if I pass the data as an array of bytes it will work?

Comment: Maybe, i don't know the mapping for java.  Also, you are using setParameter(), I don't know much about java, but isn't that call to set the parameter of a query? you might want setString() (or setBYTEA is there is such a thing).

Comment: In DB, the function signature is:

character varying, smallint, smallint, inet, character varying, character varying, json DEFAULT NULL::json)

Comment: can you edit your question and add the \d for the underlying table, and \df for the user_login function.  Your DB function declaration and the error message don't match. BUT, if the inet type in postgres can be presented as a setString() in java, then have you tried changing the setParameter() to setString() for the 'additional_data'?  Anyway, I don't think I can help here, this appears to be a hibernate question.

Comment: I don't passed `json` in hibernate (yet), but you could try `.setString("additional_data", additional_data.toString())` as native representations are in string in PostgreSQL, and (if that does not work by itself) you could rewrite your named query to end with `CAST(:additional_data AS json)`